# Spring @Bean configs and java polymorphism

Tags: java, spring

I've been making increasingly heavy use of the new `@Bean` configuration style in Spring 3, as a more type-safe alternative to XML bean definition files.  Occasionally, though, this type-safety can prevent you do what should be valid things, due to a combination of Java's lack of type expressiveness, and Spring scoped proxies.

A full unit test which demonstrates the problem is below, but briefly put I have a class `ServiceBean`, which implements interfaces `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. This bean is a scoped proxy (session-scoped in this case). I also have beans `ClientA` and `ClientB`, which are injected with objects of type `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` respectively.

In Spring XML config, there's no problem with this. Spring generates a JDK-proxy for the `ServiceBean`, which implements both interfaces, and both are injected into the client beans. It's all reflective, and the types are fine at runtime.

Try this in `@Bean`-style, though, and you have problems.  Here's the demonstrative test.

**Firstly, the services:**

```
public interface ServiceA {}

public interface ServiceB {}

public class ServiceBean implements ServiceA, ServiceB {}
```

**Now, the clients:**

```
public class ClientA {
    public ClientA(ServiceA service) {}
}    

public class ClientB {
    public ClientB(ServiceB service) {}
}
```

**Now, the Spring bean definitions:**

```
@Configuration
public class ScopedProxyConfig {

    @Bean @Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ServiceBean services() {
        return new ServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientA clientA() {
        return new ClientA(services());
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientB clientB() {
        return new ClientB(services());
    }
}
```

**And finally, the unit test and support context:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class ScopedProxyTest {

    private @Resource ClientA clientA;
    private @Resource ClientB clientB;      

    public @Test void test() {
        assertThat(clientA, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(clientB, is(notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

---

```
<beans>            
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="test.ScopedProxyConfig"/>      
</beans>
```

(XML namespaces omitted for clarity).

This all compiles nicely. Run the test, though, and you get a type casting runtime exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy11 cannot be cast to test.ServiceBean
>       at test.ScopedProxyConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d293ecc3.services()
>       at test.ScopedProxyConfig.clientA(ScopedProxyConfig.java:26)

It's not clear to me exactly what this is telling me, but it appears to be a clash between the JDK proxy (which implements `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`) and the `ServiceBean` object.

I've tried getting clever with generics:

```
@Bean @Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public <T extends ServiceA & ServiceB> T services() {
    return (T)new ServiceBean();
}
```

But that doesn't even compile.

This isn't an especially exotic situation, I think, and I've run into it a few times before. In the past, the workaround has been to use `TARGET_CLASS` proxying instead of interface proxying, but that's not an option for me here.

Can anyone figure out how to make this work?

Comment: BTW: I don't see the benefits of using the java config style. If you use STS, the XML style is much more comfortable to use, and the Spring builder will analyse and report more errors than the java compiler could ever.

Comment: @seanizer: I see what you're saying, it's a matter of personal preference. Both are valid.

Comment: true. and I know spring has been XML hell for years, but with an IDE that *understands* the XML, it's actually fun and very productive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to go for a more interface-based solution:

create an interface `ServiceC`:

```
public interface ServiceC extends ServiceA, ServiceB {}
```

and let `ServiceBean` implement that interface

```
public class ServiceBean implements ServiceC{}
```

And in your `ScopedProxyConfig`:

```
@Bean @Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION,
             proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ServiceC services() {
    return new ServiceBean();
}
```

Consistent use of interfaces should let Spring work with JDK proxies.

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering that, but the two interfaces aren't really related, so introducing an artificial umbrella type doesn't feel right. It may be the least annoying solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

This one at least compiles, perhaps it will work:

```
@Bean @Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES) 
public <T extends ServiceA & ServiceB> T services() { 
    return (T)new ServiceBean(); 
}

@Bean 
public ClientA clientA() { 
    return new ClientA(this.<ServiceBean>services()); 
} 

@Bean 
public ClientB clientB() { 
    return new ClientB(this.<ServiceBean>services()); 
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, that works for `clientA`, but fails for `clientB` with a runtime class cast exception, as though the compiler has picked the first type from the  `ServiceA & ServiceB` expression.